# Git Not Detecting Changes to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, git, github

I am working on a local version of a Wordpress website as a local Github repository. For some reason, git isn't detecting any changes that I make using the Wordpress interface itself, such as creating a new page or adding content to a page, again all from the dashboard. Git does recognize I make to files in the repository in a text editor, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is not going to track new posts because those are stored in the WordPress database.